# Structuring a PhoneGap jQuery Mobile Application

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am currently building a game in phonegap using jQuery Mobile frame work. What i have ended up with is lots of spaghetti code with one html and several js classes.

I was interested to know if there are any good guides to create a structured jQuery Mobile Application that follows MVC pattern.

I found a [good guide](http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/) for creating a MVC App with Sencha Touch. I was looking for something similar with jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have a rather large application and this is how I have it structured

```
css
    -- all css files
images
    -- all image files
js
    controller.js -- page events and element actions. Also contains PhoneGap specific methods
    core
        forms.js -- working with forms, saving info
        mobile.js -- basic definitions, AJAX communications
        encrypt.js -- encryption
        global.js   -- helper functions
        storage.js  -- database storage wrapper
    cw
        client.js -- a client object, > 400 lines of js code
        Objects.js -- all other needed objects with <50 lines of js code each
        question.js  -- a question object, > 500 lines of js code
        service.js    -- a service object, > 700 lines of js code
    jq
        jquery-ui.min.js
        jquery.min.js
        jquery.mobile.min.js
        phonegap-1.1.0.js

add_client.html
clients.html
client_list.html
index.html            -- the only file that is structured like a real full html file
manager.html
schedule.html
service.html
```

aside for my index.html file, all other .html files are stubs. They only contain the `<div data-role='page'></div>` and other needed html elements that define the page and its intended functionality.

I develop the app on VS2010, using Chrome as my debugger. When I feel good with my progress, I copy everything over to my mac to a folder in an Eclipse project ( for Android devices ) which is also a linked reference in my xCode project ( for iOS devices ).

I have been working on this project for about 3-4 months now and once I got past the learning curve of jQM and PhoneGap, have been making very good progress with this structure.

Comment: Also, I will mention, that I had never planned on building this app into one page (even though I could have) simply because I knew it would be easier to work with and keep track of if it were broken up into smaller files. I had originally had a separate .js file for each individual object (~18 objects), but found a memory utilization gain ( in chrome anyway ) when I combined files.

Comment: I use almost the same structure and it really works great. But once i read a comment: "Each page should work on it's own, because some day it will definitely get called directly". That's why all my pages are full html pages.

Comment: How do you handle partials on your pages? You may have the same header/footer that you want to show on every page. Is it possible to keep just one full HTML page, and dynamically include all other contents via ajax with standard jQuery mobile functions?

Comment: Thats a great question Mich and I havent found the answer yet ( though I am sure one could be created ). Thus far, the Headers of all of our pages are basically different as this is where we stick page specific tools\icons. The Footers of almost all of our pages  is pretty much static. Granted, we dont really add new icons to our footer, so footer management has been nil for well over 2 years now.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen the wiki entry?

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile#GettingstartedwithJQueryMobile

and to see some code have a look @

Sample Application using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap
 http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/

Comment: Yeah i have gone through both of them and they are good guides to get started with jQuery Mobile. But when the application is very complex, writing the whole application in a single html and js doesn't seem a good option. I was interested to know how write a more structured application. ie to split out the Javascripts as models(with data) and views(that alter the DOM).

Comment: @Nithin: a framework such as Durandal can help with the organization of your larger site. It does this by allowing you to use composition (the assembly of logical bits of views, etc). This means you can have an mvc like folder structure clientside and keep things manageable.